# C# Sending an object through HttpClient to a Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have a WindowsForm application and i want to send an List<> to the Web API

here is my code in the windows form app:

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/test/api/v1/name/testcontroller/");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = uri;

        var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

        HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<List<TermbaseFile>>(termbaseList, jsonFormatter);
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
```

What should i put in the controller-method to get the List?

Comment: What have you tried?  The first thing to try would be `List<Termbasefile>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `Post` action that expects a list of that particular object type, or more specifically, an object which has the same properties e.g.

```
public class TermbaseFilePostDto
{
    // relevant properties go here
}


public class TestController : ApiController
{
     public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<TermbaseFileDto> list)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```